# tesla c2075 with tensorflow cuda version installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, gpu, tesla

I'm new for GPU related model training.
I have Tesla C2075 with 6GB GPU and using keras CuDNNLSTM for faster training.
I have installed cuda-9 with cudnn=7.0.5, tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0 and using ubuntu 16.04. 
For Tesla C2075 GPU model is compatible with cuda-9?
I have checked https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus link in this they have mentioned tesla C2075 is compute compatible to 2.0. what is compute compatible?

And while running my model tensorflow log,

```
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1482] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: Tesla C2075, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 2.0) with Cuda compute capability 2.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
```

And I'm also getting error while model.fit(...),

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU,XLA_CPU,XLA_GPU], Registered kernels:
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]

[[node bidirectional_1/CudnnRNN (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/ops/cudnn_rnn_ops.py:922)  = CudnnRNN[T=DT_FLOAT, direction="unidirectional", dropout=0, input_mode="linear_input", is_training=true, rnn_mode="lstm", seed=87654321, seed2=0](bidirectional_1/transpose, bidirectional_1/ExpandDims_1, bidirectional_1/ExpandDims_2, bidirectional_1/concat)]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CUDA compute capability relates somehow to the architecture and hardware capabilities of the GPU, there is quite an extensive list in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported).

[The tensoflow webpage suggests](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) that you need a GPU with CC bigger than 3.5 (older versions seemed to accept 3.0, but never lower).

Unfortunately this is a hardware limitation, the only way of changing your compute capability is using a different GPU. Simply said: you can not run Tensorflow in that GPU.